# bit accurate(more or less) opencv/C++ smoothing function (imfilter) to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

```
h = fspecial('average', filterSize);
 imageData = imfilter(imageData, h, 'replicate');
```

in my matlab code i apply averaging filter to an image.

I saw this article for openCV smoothing: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html 

since i need it to be bit accurate, can you suggest some smoothing function **which is bit accurate to matlab**?

Comment: Highly unlikely I would have thought - is there some special reason why it has to be bit accurate ?

Comment: @PaulR i'm trying to convert code from matlab to C++ since the algorithm is very complex. I would like to create bit accurate c++ version and after that try to optimize and change it. I can always go into matlab and check the code and implement the kernel on my own, but maybe gaussian filter is bit accurate so I don't need to...

Comment: I think you'll probably just have to accept that any testing/validation you plan to do will have to allow for a tolerance when comparing outputs from each implementation. This is a very common requirement for numerical code - bit level accuracy is almost impossible to achieve in practice for anything but the most trivial programs.

Comment: @PaulR I don't expect 7 digits precision. i expect something like plus or mins 0.001 is close enough, for example imresize() and cv::resize() have the same output for bilinear interpolation.

Comment: OK, but "bit accurate" to me suggests that you want the output to match exactly, i.e. zero tolerance. I see you've now added the "more or less" qualifier though.

Comment: @PaulR I'm not a native English speaker maybe i'm missing the right expression here... bit accurate might be exaggerated...

Comment: Averaging is a pretty simple operation, it should be possible to get it bit accurate. I think you want the [Normalized Box Filter](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#normalized-box-filter).

Comment: @JoseMarquesJunior You could have corrected the name of OpenCV while you were at it, and maybe even capitalized the initial letter of the title and corrected the spacing before the opening parenthesis. And that doesn't even mention the capitalization errors in the question body. I should also note that MathWorks currently prefers MATLAB in all caps. In short, if you're going to make 3 other users (at least) review your edit suggestion, please make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [blur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#blur) function.

```
blur(inIamge, outImage, Size(filterSize,filterSize));
```

Comment: there is a difference between the two

Comment: More than one gray level?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001598/opencv-blur-vs-fspecialaverage I opened a new question for that