# opencv blur() vs. fspecial('average')

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

my filterSize =2

```
   h = fspecial('average', filterSize);
   imageData = imfilter(imageData, h, 'replicate');
```

meaning my kernel is 1/4 1/4 and so on..

I'm using

```
cv::blur(dst, dst,cv::Size(filterSize,filterSize));
```

so I should get the same results.
however the openCV results has a duplicated line, probably due to circular or some other sort of padding for the matrix.
line 0 and line 1 are the same.

can you suggest for it to be without that line

openCV results:

```
  0.027027026, 0.027027026, 0.022727273, 0.018427517, 0.017199017, 0.017813267, 
  0.027027026, 0.027027026, 0.022727273, 0.018427517, 0.017199017, 0.017813267,
  0.02948403, 0.02948403, 0.027641278, 0.028255528, 0.03194103, 0.03194103,
  0.054054055, 0.054054055, 0.055896807, 0.064496316, 0.077395573, 0.079852581,
  0.11240786, 0.11240786, 0.11855037, 0.13513513, 0.14864865, 0.1566339,
  0.16646191, 0.16646191, 0.17383292, 0.18611793, 0.18673219, 0.19471744,
  0.18243243, 0.18243243, 0.19471744, 0.19594595, 0.18796068, 0.1928747,
```

Matlab results:

```
0.0270270   0.022727    0.018427    0.017199    0.017813  0.0251842
0.029484    0.027641    0.028255    0.031941    0.031941  0.0350122
0.0540540   0.055896    0.064496    0.077395    0.079852  0.0847665
0.1124078   0.118550    0.135135    0.148648    0.156633  0.1683046
0.1664619   0.173832    0.186117    0.186732    0.194717  0.2057739
0.1824324   0.194717    0.195945    0.187960    0.192874  0.1947174
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is in the blur filter, and not in the OpenCV result dumping routine?

Comment: @rolfl until now it worked fine. I always got the expected results so I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Your kernel size is even, which is probably why OpenCV differs from MATLAB.  It gets ambiguous when the filter is evenly sized because the kernel is not symmetric when it is centered at each pixel when you're doing the filtering.  Does your kernel size have to be even?   Do you get same results between MATLAB and OpenCV when the kernel size is odd?

Comment: @rayryeng kernel must even 2x2

Comment: @Gilad - Does it happen for all images you use?  If you're dead set on using a 2 x 2 kernel size, then simply create a new image that removes the first row.

Comment: @rayryeng the problem is that if I have an image let's say 100X40, from matlab i'm getting back 100X40 but if i remove one line i will have 99X44 from openCV...

Comment: @Gilad - I can't comment on how OpenCV handles the borders or how it filters pixels when the kernel size is even.  The only way I know where you will get consistent results is if the kernel size is odd.  Maybe what you could do is artificially pad the kernel so that it becomes 3 x 3 - Make an extra row of zeroes and an extra column of zeroes.  Run this new kernel through MATLAB and OpenCV, and see what the results are.

Comment: @Gilad - Cool!  Let me know what happens!